# How to return two specific types from a generic method?

Tags: dart

```
T getValue<T>(int i) {
  if (T == String) return '$i'; // Error
  return i; // Error
}


void main() {
  var s = getValue<String>(1);
  var i = getValue<int>(1);
}
```

I want `getValue` to return string if `T` is `String` and `int` otherwise. How to do that?

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Could you explain what you expect generics to do in this case? What's wrong with a `dynamic` return value?

Comment: @ChristopherMoore I've updated the code, can you please check?

Comment: Probably not a good place for generics, but maybe someone else will see it differently.

Comment: At the very least, I don't see you using generics for the return type of the function. Even assuming the return under the if statement worked, there is nothing that can be done about returning `int i` if I pass `List` as the generic.

Comment: Since you're relying on the caller to specify `T` anyway, there's not much advantage to having a generic `getValue` function over separate `getStringValue` and `getIntValue` functions (and at that point, why even bother with functions).  This smells a bit like an X-Y problem: *why* do you want this? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @jamesdlin Actually sir, I thought I could use something like `T extends String, int`, if you can see my old post (prior to edit), you may get an idea. I thought something like this can be done in Dart. If nothing worked, I'd go with your choice of using `getStringValue` and `getIntValue`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't restrict the type parameter to just `int` or `String`, so it will have to accept more than that (at least their least common supertype, `Object`, so basically any type).

It's not a particularly helpful way to code. It's possible, but not recommended:

```dart
T getValue<T>(int i) {
  if (i is T) return i;
  return "$i" as T;
}
```

This will return the `int` if `T` allows it (so `T` being any of `int`, or a super type of `int`, which is `num`, `Object`, `dynamic` or `void`, or any number of `Comparable<X>` wrappings around any any of those supertypes), and otherwise try to return a string. That will fail with a type error unless `T` is `String` (since we've already ruled out all supertypes of `String`).
You can still call it as `getValue<bool>(42)` and watch it fail, so the type argument doesn't help with correctness.

It's not particularly effective. I'd rather do:

```dart
dynamic getValue(int i, {bool toString = false}) {
  if (toString) return "$i";
  return i;
}
```

and call it as:

```dart
  String x = getValue(42, toString: true); // Add `as String` if you disable downcasts.
  int y = getValue(42); // And `as int` here.
```

The type parameter is really just making things harder. You *are* going to cast or type-check the result anyway, so might as well do it at the call point, rather than introduce type variables that aren't actually preventing misuse anyway.

(I'd probably just do two different functions, but I assume that there is a reason for wanting one function).

Comment: Thanks sir for such a nice explanation why something would work and why it wouldn't. However, in your first code (which I also tried before posting the question), there's a compile time error, you can't return `int` from a method with return type `T`. Just because my function is too long and only for a specific case I need to use string part, I needed one function as your last line said :)

Answer (score 0):

As I mentioned in the comments, I don't see any way that you could use your generic as the return type of your `getValue` function. Even assuming the return under the if statement worked, there is nothing that can be done about trying to return `int i` when `List` is passed as the type. You'll be trying to return an `int` as a `List`.

If you change it to `dynamic`, your code will work fine as it's just using the generic as another parameter.

```dart
dynamic getValue<T>(int i) {
  if (T == String) return '$i';
  return i;
}


void main() {
  var s = getValue<String>(1);
  var i = getValue<int>(1);
}
```

Comment: I know `dynamic` and `Object` both would work but that just beats the type sound purpose. I thought there exists some way of doing what I was looking for.